# Maintain LOG files - ODBC connection in Tableau to Snowflake

Tags: logging, odbc, tableau-api, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are using Tableau and we are connecting to Snowflake via Tableau SF connector. We can check LOG parameters in registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Snowflake\Driver.

We have a problem, how to maintain the log file.

- Are there any **parameters** that we can control **max log file size**
  (maxFileSize) and **max retention log files rolling** (maxBackupIndex)?
- What is the proper way to **clean the log file**?

We have checked the following links, but we cannot find answers (we can change logLevel)

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-parameters.html#setting-parameters-in-windows
- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-parameters.html#configuration-parameters
- https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors

[logging parameters example in registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7No2Z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The improvements for ODBC log settings have been added to version [2.23.2](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/client-change-log-odbc.html)

Unfortunately they aren't yet reflected properly in the ODBC configuration parameters documentation, but as of 2.23.2 there 2 extra parameters besides **LogLevel** and **LogPath**:

**LogFileSize**

**LogFileCount**

Comment: How to enter value for LogFIleSize?
Is it
* integer size in kb
* string with size units for this property b, kb, mb, and gb >> for example '1gb'

Comment: @ZaneLogar LogFileSize represents the maximum size of each log file in bytes. After the maximum file size is reached, the driver creates a new file and continues logging.